# image_composite (Magick) return error in Shiny Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I need to build a composite picture in a Shiny Flexdashboard to place a Ggplot2 chart on a background image.

I use the following code:

````
```{r}

renderImage({

bkgDom <- image_read('background.png')
myChart <- ggplot(data=individualObs, aes(individualObs$SA)) + geom_histogram()
fig <- image_graph(width = 600, height = 550)
myChart
dev.off()
image_composite(bkgDom, fig, offset = "+1030+50", operator = "multiply") }, deleteFile = TRUE)
````

The code inside the renderImage() works fine in RStudio but returns the error "object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable" when used in the Shiny Flexdashboard code.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your kind support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason there is an issue with the tempfile and therefore I've used the image_write() function to save the result of image_composite() and then retrieve the file with the list() function.

Further to this and to avoid the creation of an empty file, the Ggplot2 chart has to be exposed through the print() function.

Here is the code that works within Shiny Flexidashboard:

```
renderImage({

#Set the first image-magic pointer
bkgDom <- image_read('background.png')

myChart <- ggplot(data=individualObs, aes(individualObs$SA)) + geom_histogram()

#Set the space to load the Ggplot chart in
fig <- image_graph(width = 400, height = 400)

#Print the Ggplot chart into the fig pointer
print(myChart)

#Create the composite image into a image-magick pointer and adjust the position
pic <- image_composite(bkgDom, fig, offset = "+580-25", operator = "multiply")

#Save the pointer into a png file
image_write(pic,"test.png")

#Read and show the png file
list(src = "test.png", contentType = 'image/png', width="100%")

}, deleteFile = TRUE)
```

Comment: glad it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the docs](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/renderImage.html), it says the expression is supposed to return a list. Since what you wrote returns an object of type 'externalptr' *(or so I'm guessing the `image_composite()` docs doesn't tell me the value of the ouput)*, I think the error is because shiny can't look for the src. Also, your composite image might need to be temporarily saved as well.

Didn't have enough code to reproduce, but from the docs this should fix :

```r
renderImage({
  
  bkgDom <- image_read('background.png')
  myChart <- ggplot(data=individualObs, aes(individualObs$SA)) + geom_histogram()
  fig <- image_graph(width = 600, height = 550)
  myChart
  dev.off()

  # A temp file to save the output.
  outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
  png(outfile)
  image_composite(bkgDom, fig, offset = "+1030+50", operator = "multiply")
  dev.off() 
  
  # Return a list containing the filename
  list(src = outfile,
       alt = "This is alternate text")
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
```

I saved the composite it seperatly, but this could probably be done in step with the other image you modify?

If this doesn't work, could you provide more code to make it reproducible?

Comment: The suggested code remove the error message from the page but the image is not visible on the dashboard. Code, data and background image available

  [1]: https://www.acceleration-lab.com/agility/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Sample_Shiny.Rmd
  [2]: https://www.acceleration-lab.com/agility/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/data.csv
  [3]: https://www.acceleration-lab.com/agility/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/bkgDomainsActivation.png

Comment: hmm that's weird. Thanks for the code, I'll look at it.

Comment: Right, I've been trying several variation without success. I trust the issue is due to the fact that the image_composite generate a Magick pointer and not an image.